# material design component - issue when added width, height in cards

Tags: css, material-design, angular-material

```
<div class="mdc-card problem">
        <section class="mdc-card__primary">
            <h1 class="mdc-card__title mdc-card__title--large">title here</h1>
            <h2 class="mdc-card__subtitle">subtitle here</h2>
        </section>
        <section class="mdc-card__supporting-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam nostrum nisi optio iusto excepturi sequi itaque. Vitae laudantium fugiat, id eius voluptates placeat labore magnam est saepe sapiente et molestias quaerat numquam excepturi illum dolores quam error, eaque rerum ea vero ipsum sequi. Sapiente adipisci reiciendis quod officia aliquam quidem praesentium cupiditate facere, magni nemo, asperiores, reprehenderit eveniet corporis eligendi et. Numquam voluptatem, consectetur. A harum quas, veritatis blanditiis, officia impedit voluptas laborum itaque delectus dolore explicabo aut, culpa iste sapiente repellat voluptate voluptates commodi dignissimos similique repudiandae. Nulla expedita atque dolore alias, facilis ipsam qui doloribus, iure quo animi.
        </section>
        <section class="mdc-card__actions">
            <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--compact mdc-card__action">action 1</button>
            <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--compact mdc-card__action">action 2</button>
        </section>
    </div>
```

---

```
.problem {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e9x6od1e/)  - the demo first row is full width no issues, the problem  with second row with large supporting text, and third one with small supporting text

[mdc-card - docs](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/cards/)

how to deal with the width and height of the cards.

what the best way to handle this kind of issues

Answer (score 0):

add only `width` [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e9x6od1e/1/)

or

if all cards what to be in same height - add `height`, `overflow: hidden;` to `mdc-card__supporting-text` class [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e9x6od1e/4/)

as of now ended like this